# Unable to connect hyperledger fabric network to the explorer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have set up a fabric network (v1.1.0) on a ubuntu 16.04 VM. I want to connect that network to the hyper ledger explorer to see the blocks and the ledger copies at different peers,for which I am using this https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer repo.

Compilation warning when I tried to build explorer

```
nik@nik-VirtualBox:~/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/client$ npm run build

 hyperledger-explorer-client@0.3.0 build /home/nik/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/client
react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/View/LandingPage.js
  Line 18:  'getChannelListCreator' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 19:  'getChannelCreator' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars

./src/components/Panels/Notifications.js
  Line 19:  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor

./src/components/Lists/Chaincodes.js
  Line 7:  'Pagination' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/Forms/Channel.js
  Line 8:   'Input' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  Line 8:   'InputLabel' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  Line 9:   'FormGroup' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  Line 9:   'FormControl' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
  Line 9:   'FormHelperText' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 29:  Useless constructor                         no-useless-constructor

./src/components/Lists/Blocks.js
  Line 95:  Links must not point to "#". Use a more descriptive href or use a button instead  jsx-a11y/href-no-hash

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  332.32 KB  build/static/js/main.e33e1c6b.js
  22.58 KB   build/static/css/main.1f5927af.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
```

I tried running the explorer, I could see the logs but when I launch http://localhost:8080 it shows error

Logs :

```
nik@nik-VirtualBox:~/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer$ ./start.sh
nik@nik-VirtualBox:~/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer$ tail -f log.log
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at setupPeers (/home/nik/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/helper.js:60:19)
    at Object.createDefault (/home/nik/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/helper.js:50:4)
    at Object.start (/home/nik/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/timer/timer.js:38:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nik/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/main.js:25:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that currently, Hyperledger Explorer does not yet work with Hyperledger Fabric v1.1.x. See the [README](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#requirements)